# Why Array.new(3, []) works differently than [[], [], []] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain this to me:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Array.new(3, [])                      
=> [[], [], []]                                           

irb(main):001:0> b = [[], [], []]                         
=> [[], [], []]                                           

irb(main):003:0> a.each_with_index{ |r, idx| r << 'a' }   
=> [["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a"]]    

irb(main):004:0> b.each_with_index{ |r, idx| r << 'a' }   
=> [["a"], ["a"], ["a"]]
```

Comment: A search for ["\[ruby\] Array.new"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+Array.new) will turn up more duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `.new` method:

> Since all the Array elements store the same hash, changes to one of them will affect them all.

If multiple copies are what you want, you should use the block version which uses the result of that block each time an element of the array needs to be initialized:

```
2.3.0 :001 > a = Array.new(3) { [] }
 => [[], [], []]
2.3.0 :002 > a.each_with_index{ |r, idx| r << 'a' }
 => [["a"], ["a"], ["a"]]
```

Read the examples here - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new