# Trouble with arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I make an array and edit values:

```
arr = Array.new(6, Array.new(2, '0'))
arr[0][0] = 'name'
arr[1][0] = 'id'
arr[2][0] = 'type'
arr[3][0] = 'sum'
arr[4][0] = 'partner'
arr[5][0] = 'time'
```

And after that i have this array:

```
[["time", "0"], ["time", "0"], ["time", "0"], ["time", "0"], ["time", "0"], ["time", "0"]]
```

When i need this:

```
[["name", "0"], ["id", "0"], ["type", "0"], ["sum", "0"], ["partner", "0"], ["time", "0"]]
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: See also [Creating matrix with Array.new(n, Array.new)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22417074/479863), [Why Array.new(3, \[\]) works differently ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42615737/479863), and lots of others. Don't feel bad, the duplicates aren't easy to find (unless you know the answer already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Ruby Array docs:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html

`Note that the second argument populates the array with references to the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as Symbols, numbers, true or false.`

Which explains why

```
arr[0][0] = 'name'
```

Sets all keys to the same value. In your case the last-one wins so its `time`

What are you really trying to achieve? Setting a default value? If so, use the block syntax to pre-fill your array, like:

```
 arr = Array.new(6) { [2, '0'] }
```

Comment: I'm trying to make an array with pairs of values. I had the same trouble with 2-dimensional arrays in ruby everytime i set values using something like `arr[0][0] = 'name'`. I think that's the wrong way to work with 2d-arrays but i haven't found any other ways.

Comment: @M.Sakovich First of all, there are no 2D arrays in Ruby, just arrays-of-arrays; a minor point perhaps but it underlies the real problem of accidental reference sharing. If you want to make an array-of-arrays, use the block form of `Array.new` as Cody suggests: `Array.new(n) { [ ] }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = Array.new(6){Array.new(2,'0')}
arr[0][0] = 'pan'
arr[1][0] = 'id'
arr[2][0] = 'type'
arr[3][0] = 'sum'
arr[4][0] = 'partner'
arr[5][0] = 'time'
puts arr
```

Try This.